# Need to check both condition token not in cache plus token expires less than utc now

Tags: c#

Below code throwing argument null exception for `token.ExpiresOn` since token is not in cache and `null`. Is there way to check both in `IF` clause - token not in cache plus token expires less than utc now?

```
if (!_cache.TryGetValue("KEY", out TokenClass token) && token.ExpiresOn < DateTimeOffset.UtcNow)
        {

        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really want to check if the token is not in cache *or* if it's expired. So just use `||`:

```
if (!_cache.TryGetValue("KEY", out TokenClass token) || token.ExpiresOn < DateTimeOffset.UtcNow)
{
    // presumably, get a new token
}
```

This work because `||` is short-circuiting: if the left-hand part evaluates to `true`, the right hand part is not evaluated (that code doesn't run). And so, if your token is not in cache, no need to check if it's expired (which is good because then you'd throw).

Comment: Thank you very much for detail explanation @Etienne de Martel. Appreciate!